# How do I check for HTTP status inside libcurl callback?

Tags: c, http, curl, callback, libcurl

It's already been covered how to get the response code in this question:

[Http status code with libcurl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290996/http-status-code-with-libcurl)

And how to receive data with a callback here:

[libcurl HTTPS POST data send?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850716/libcurl-https-post-data-send)

My question is about receiving or checking the status *inside the callback.*

Points to consider:

- The callback does not receive the CURL handle by default.  That means I don't know if it's safe to call functions like `curl_easy_getinfo()` inside it, if I pass the CURL handle myself.
- I want the information inside the callback, so it can decide how to operate based on whether the HTTP status code is 200, or something else.
- I can't just check after the call to `curl_easy_perform()` because that would defeat the purpose of my callback.
- [The documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) doesn't say anything about the behaviour of calling `curl_easy_*()` functions inside the callback, so at a first guess I think it's unsafe to do.

Do I have any options to do this?

**EDIT**: The book [Everything Curl](https://www.gitbook.com/book/bagder/everything-curl/details) by Daniel Steinberg says

> These information values are designed to be provided *after* the transfer is completed.

And so I will not be "accepting" my own answer.

Comment: I think, you can provide the CURL handle inside the userdata argument (either directly or, if you need to pass more data, inside a struct). Then you can call curl_easy_getinfo() inside your callback using this handle. This should be safe.

Comment: AFAIK, it is safe to call most curl functions, except `perform`, from within the callback (and `perform` is only unsafe because of possibility of recursion). If the status code hasn't been received yet, the function might return error or -1, but nothing bad should happen.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Ctk and user1643723 are correct.

With

```
curl_easy_setopt( handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, handle );
```

before `curl_easy_perform()` and the following in my callback,

```
long code = -1;
curl_easy_getinfo( handle, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &code );
/* superfluous printf() */
printf( "HTTP Response Code: %ld\n", code );
```

I have the HTTP status inside it.

I would be more comfortable if the libcurl documentation explicitly said this was OK.